# If $x_n\rightarrow\alpha$, then $x_n\leq \alpha +\rho_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

If $x_n$ is a sequence of real numbers and $x_n\rightarrow\alpha$, then I wonder if we can claim that there is a sequence $\rho_n$ converging to zero such that $x_n\leq \alpha +\rho_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$?.
I am stucked. I tried with the definition of convergent sequence but then I can't say "  for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ ".

Any comment is welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, for instance $\rho_n=\lvert x_n-\alpha\rvert$.